# Autolayout view swapping

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

When swapping a sub view with another sun view, is it necessary to reapply constraints?
Do constraints need to be removed that apply to a view that is removed?

Or should they persist automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints are "part of" a view. When you remove a view (with `removeFromSuperview`), they stay with that view, provided that the view itself isn't being deallocated. You can then safely add the view again and the constraints will take care of positioning.

Compare it to a view's frame: even when you remove a view from its superview, the frame will remain the same. When you add the view back as a subview, it will be in the exact same position as it was before.

So, to answer your question: when you "swap" a view with another view, the new view won't have any constraints. This wouldn't work:

```
[newView addConstraints:[oldView constraints]];
```

It will cause a "view not in hierarchy" error, because the constraints are tied to `oldView`.

Comment: So, we should not try to "copy" constraints from a view to a replacement view...? I'm still trying to grok what a constraint contains. I suspect the API will get better eventually. But If I understand correctly, a constraint is tightly coupled to a relationship with one or two view objects.

Comment: Not having luck with what you describe adding it back and the frame being the same. In fact I get a zero frame.

Comment: So in practice in fact, when I re add the subview it doesn't appear. I must be doing something wrong.